# User and Profile - Which Gets The Foreign Key To The Other?

Tags: database, foreign-keys

The User table contains administrative info like username, password, and email.

A Profile has all the other information like about me, names, social network URLs, etc.

A profile isn't required. (A profile isn't created until the user fills in profile info and saves it).

So, I've seen 2 implementations:

1. Only User has a ProfileId FK to Profile - ProfileId is nullable and has a SET NULL delete rule.
2. Only Profile has a UserId FK to User - UserId is required, thus, non-nullable, and the DELETE CASCADE delete rule.

I don't think they're equivalent. Where would each situation fit better when a user doesn't always have to have a profile associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and a few discoveries, Profile gets the UserId FK based on the Principal/Dependent concept.

User is the principal because it can exist independently without even knowledge that a profile exists. The Profile is the dependent, which bears the foreign key column, and it being dependent means it can't exist until the User is created to give its newly-generated Id to Profile's UserId.